# My app crashes when the Admob ad is displayed (Interstitial Ad)

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

My Application crashes after pressing the Button "mMyButton". Sometimes, but really rare it works, and i don't know why.

In the xml File is only the Button "mMyButton".

Can you help me, because I've tried many different methods, but it never worked.

```
package com.example.rapha.rafisapp.Firebase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rapha.rafisapp.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class Admob_Interstitial extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private static final String TAG = "lollogtag";
private Toast toast = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admob__interstitial);

    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    Button mMyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9955387151447653~2362893982");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9955387151447653/8105410912");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    mMyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                Log.d(TAG, "ad loaded and shown");
                toast.setText("Loaded");
                toast.show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                toast.setText("The Ad wasn't loaded yet");
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: capture logs and update in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself!

I tried to use a different version and it works every time